# Preloader vuelve a aparecer despues de refrescar la pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy teniendo un problema [Hice esta pagina web](https://candymania.000webhostapp.com/index.html)

funciona como lo espero pero si la abro en chrome del celular luego de refrescar la pagina o de ir a otra pagina el preloader vuelve a aparecer, ¿alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

**Este es el código html**:

```
<br> 
<body>
<div id="preloader">
    <div class="cssload-loader-inner">
        <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
            <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
            <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
            <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
            <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cssload-cssload-loader-line-wrap-wrap">
            <div class="cssload-loader-line-wrap"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body> 
<br>
```

**Este es el css**:

```
#preloader{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 99999;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000000;
}`<br>Y este el javascript relevante:<br>

$(window).on("load", function(){
$("#preloader").fadeOut("slow");    
});
```

Comment: Puedes ocultarlo hasta que cargue el documento $(document).ready(function(){ $("#preloader").fadeOut("slow"); });

Comment: no me entro en el codigo pero tambien puse eso y no funciona, si entras a la pagina y ves el codigo fuente ahi sale el archivo javascript, no se porque no anda en mobile se buguea eso

Comment: Me funciono bien en mobil, si se muestra pero desaparece en cuanto carga el sitio. Lo probe en Android

Comment: pero le diste a recargar? a mi lo que me pasa es que cuando recargo la pagina o voy a otra pagina se queda y no desaparece, eso es lo que no quiero que pase

Comment: si lo abro en modo incógnito anda bien, pero aparece el banner abajo del servidor cosa que en modo normal no aparece, estoy empezando a creer que es cosa del server ese 000webhost...

Comment: Prueba a cargar el código que oculta el preloader en lo ultimo que cargue tu server así te aseguras que primero cargue todo el código y luego ejecute el hide(), el código que te paso es JQuery así que deberías incluir la librería para que funcione https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/

Comment: @RubenHernandez ya tenia agregado jquery, le aplique el hide y sigue igual, en ventana de incognito por alguna razon anda bien, lo mismo que en la pc

Comment: MMM crees que pueda ser el cache del server??? header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");

Comment: No se por lo que veo al refrescar la pagina o ir a otra pagina no se dispara el evento "on load" del javascript :/

Comment: Prueba el "ready" el "onload" se usa para precargar y el ready cuando esta listo

Comment: El tema es que lo ponia en el onload porque en el ready se va a ocultar muy rapido el preloader y queria que se oculte cuando esta todo listo

Comment: Mira checa el ejemplo que te paso como respuesta, espero te sirva de algo :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luego de buscar encontre la solución en este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810825/javascript-event-window-onload-not-triggered<br)

**Al colocar este código:**

```
window.addEventListener ? 
window.addEventListener("load",yourFunction,false) : 
window.attachEvent && window.attachEvent("onload",yourFunction);
```

Luego con eso si detecta el evento load en mobile y le agrego la funcion

```
$(".preloader").fadeOut("slow");
```

Y ahi si funciona al recargar la pagina anda bien. 
Gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Mira este ejemplo

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="Cargando">Cargando...</div>
....
```

Ponlo al iniciar tu sitio que sea lo primero que cargue la pagina

**JS**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#Cargando").hide();
        },100);
    });
    </script>
```

Esto lo pones al final de tu pagina, ya que cargaste todo el HTML, CSS, etc

y por ultimo

**CSS**

```
<style>
#Cargando{width:100%;height:9999%;position:absolute;top:0px;padding:0px;background:white;text-align:center;z-index:9999;padding-top:20px;color:black;;}
</style>
```

Esto lo pones en el `head` de tu sitio

Espero sirva de algo, Saludos :)